# How to paste tag 'br' after label of django form field?

Tags: django

I have a form:

```
class AddNewContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=True, label='Enter contact name')
    number = forms.IntegerField(required=False, label='Enter contact phone number')
```

and i would to have tag 'br' after label of field to print label above data of tag input

Comment: It is better to do that by css and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in your template

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{ form.name.label_tag }}</label><br/><!--added br tag here-->
  {{ form.name }}<!--here your input-->
  <span class="text-danger">
   {{ form.name.errors }}<!--this is for any error -->
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways.

You might be able to get the formatting you want using css.

You might write a template which renders the form at a higher level of granularity, so you can explicitly code the tags you require.

Here's an article which covers both these in detail.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html

I'll also  mention  the entirely awesome Crispy Forms package, specifically, a `FormHelper` with an `HTML` layout object to inject `<br>`.
I appreciate that some employers might not want to depend on added packages for mission-critical stuff.
[Crispy Forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)